# Angular 4 HttpClient Module not working on production build

Tags: angular, httpclient

My angular version is 4.3.6

I built my app separately in 2 different environments (dev and prod), using `ng build --dev` and `ng build --prod`

And serve these in node.js with express, and just call a sample web service call with HttpClient.

```
this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                .subscribe(data => { console.log(data);},
                           error => { console.log(error);});
```

The one that was built with --dev, can fetch the JSON and log to the console.
But the one that was built with --prod, does not file any calls (I inspected in Network tab of dev tool) then just return an empty object `{}` .

Why?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I can close this question. It is because I had a Mockup Interceptor after I removed it, dev and prod behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CLI Try this.

```
ng build --base-href /"folder name in server"/
```